# Inconsistent servers - SharePoint Servers are inconsistent with SQL Server

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

We have 4 SharePoint servers in a Farm and SQL Server. During an activity, we restored the SharePoint servers but not the SQL Server. The complete environment is running fine though it is not a Microsoft`s best practice.

Just want to understand if the environment can continue to be inconsistent as it is running fine or we might end up facing any issues? Are there any known issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by restore, you mean a VM online backup restore, yes this is considered unsupported. That said, the procedure you should follow is to clear the Config Cache on all SharePoint servers in the farm. Search should be recreated. This more or less follows Azure Site Recovery procedures, the only method supported by Microsoft for VM replication.

[Replicate a multi-tier SharePoint application for disaster recovery using Azure Site Recovery](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/site-recovery-sharepoint)

Comment: Those are VM Servers, Any particular reasons why search should be recreated? Apart from search, are there any known issues with supported reference links?

Comment: The issue is Search can't really be made to be crash consistent for a multi-server farm between the indexes as well as the Search databases themselves. But again, Microsoft doesn't support this outside of ASR so "known issues" isn't something they'll list.